# WPF textbox and browse file - is there a more elegant solution?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, openfiledialog

i have a simple textbox + file dialog scenario. the textbox is bound to an object in a colooection. i want to select the file and have it populate the text box, which in turn will update the bound object property. managed to get the filename into the textbox, but then the textbox binding was not firing because it didn't detect a change. i had to add a focus() change to trigger the update. is there a better way?

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=FlexString1,Mode=TwoWay}" 
         Height="23" 
         HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
         Margin="10" Name="textPath" 
         VerticalAlignment="Top" 
         Width="236" />
<Button Height="25" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
        Margin="0" 
        Name="btnBrowseFile" 
        Padding="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
        Width="45" Click="btnBrowseFile_Click">
  <TextBlock FontSize="10" 
             FontWeight="Normal" 
             Foreground="#FF3C3C3C" 
             Text="Browse" 
             TextWrapping="Wrap" />
</Button>

private void btnBrowseFile_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Configure open file dialog box
    Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
    //dlg.FileName = "Document"; // Default file name
    //dlg.DefaultExt = ".txt"; // Default file extension
    //dlg.Filter = "Text documents (.txt)|*.txt"; // Filter files by extension

    // Show open file dialog box
    Nullable<bool> result = dlg.ShowDialog();

    // Process open file dialog box results
    if (result == true)
    {
        // Open document
        TextBox path = (TextBox)(((FrameworkElement)sender).Parent as FrameworkElement).FindName("textPath");
        path.Text = dlg.FileName;
        path.Focus(); //these 2 lines force the binding to trigger
        ((Button)sender).Focus();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just set the view model property `FlexString1` directly.

The binding will ensure that the UI gets updated correctly.

You could also put the browse dialog on a command so it's done from within the view model rather than the view.

Answer (score 2):

The TextBox's default update is on LostFocus. Try changing it to PropertyChanged instead:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=FlexString1,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```